# Spring Boot WebSocket Application Hangs with all threads in blocked State

Tags: java, spring-boot, threadpool, embedded-jetty, spring-websocket

I am facing an issue where all the threads of my spring boot application went into a BLOCKED state. The server was running fine for a long time and it suddenly hung. Below is the thread dump:

```
Thread 227: (state = IN_NATIVE)
 - sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl$SubSelector.poll0(long, int, int[], int[], int[], long) @bci=0 (Compiled frame; information may be imprecise)
 - sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl$SubSelector.poll() @bci=43 (Compiled frame)
 - sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl$SubSelector.access$400(sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl$SubSelector) @bci=1 (Compiled frame)
 - sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl.doSelect(long) @bci=63 (Compiled frame)
 - sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.lockAndDoSelect(long) @bci=37 (Compiled frame)
 - sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(long) @bci=30 (Compiled frame)
 - sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select() @bci=2 (Compiled frame)
 - org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector$SelectorProducer.select() @bci=64, line=422 (Compiled frame)
 - org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector$SelectorProducer.produce() @bci=20, line=359 (Compiled frame)
 - org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.produceTask() @bci=4, line=357 (Compiled frame)
 - org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(boolean) @bci=1, line=181 (Compiled frame)
 - org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(boolean) @bci=134, line=168 (Compiled frame)
 - org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run() @bci=2, line=126 (Compiled frame)
 - org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run() @bci=203, line=366 (Compiled frame)
 - org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(java.lang.Runnable) @bci=1, line=765 (Compiled frame)
 - org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run() @bci=104, line=683 (Compiled frame)
 - java.lang.Thread.run() @bci=11 (Compiled frame)


Thread 226: (state = BLOCKED)
 - sun.misc.Unsafe.park(boolean, long) @bci=0 (Compiled frame; information may be imprecise)
 - java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(java.lang.Object, long) @bci=20 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(long, java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit) @bci=97 (Compiled frame)
 - org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.reservedWait() @bci=97, line=292 (Compiled frame)
 - org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run() @bci=188, line=357 (Compiled frame)
 - org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(java.lang.Runnable) @bci=1, line=765 (Compiled frame)
 - org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run() @bci=104, line=683 (Compiled frame)
 - java.lang.Thread.run() @bci=11 (Compiled frame)


Thread 225: (state = BLOCKED)
 - sun.misc.Unsafe.park(boolean, long) @bci=0 (Compiled frame; information may be imprecise)
 - java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(java.lang.Object, long) @bci=20 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(long) @bci=78 (Compiled frame)
 - org.eclipse.jetty.util.BlockingArrayQueue.poll(long, java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit) @bci=57, line=392 (Compiled frame)
 - org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.idleJobPoll() @bci=12, line=656 (Compiled frame)
 - org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.access$800(org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool) @bci=1, line=49 (Compiled frame)
 - org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run() @bci=358, line=720 (Compiled frame)
 - java.lang.Thread.run() @bci=11 (Compiled frame)


Thread 224: (state = BLOCKED)
 - sun.misc.Unsafe.park(boolean, long) @bci=0 (Compiled frame; information may be imprecise)
 - java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(java.lang.Object, long) @bci=20 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(long) @bci=78 (Compiled frame)
 - org.eclipse.jetty.util.BlockingArrayQueue.poll(long, java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit) @bci=57, line=392 (Compiled frame)
 - org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.idleJobPoll() @bci=12, line=656 (Compiled frame)
 - org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.access$800(org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool) @bci=1, line=49 (Compiled frame)
 - org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run() @bci=358, line=720 (Compiled frame)
 - java.lang.Thread.run() @bci=11 (Compiled frame)


Thread 223: (state = BLOCKED)
 - sun.misc.Unsafe.park(boolean, long) @bci=0 (Compiled frame; information may be imprecise)
 - java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(java.lang.Object, long) @bci=20 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(long, java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit) @bci=97 (Compiled frame)
 - org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.reservedWait() @bci=97, line=292 (Compiled frame)
 - org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run() @bci=188, line=357 (Compiled frame)
 - org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(java.lang.Runnable) @bci=1, line=765 (Compiled frame)
 - org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run() @bci=104, line=683 (Compiled frame)
 - java.lang.Thread.run() @bci=11 (Compiled frame)


Thread 221: (state = BLOCKED)
 - sun.misc.Unsafe.park(boolean, long) @bci=0 (Compiled frame; information may be imprecise)
 - java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(java.lang.Object, long) @bci=20 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(long) @bci=78 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take() @bci=124 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take() @bci=1 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask() @bci=149 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker) @bci=26 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run() @bci=5 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.lang.Thread.run() @bci=11 (Interpreted frame)


Thread 1: (state = BLOCKED)


Thread 220: (state = BLOCKED)
 - org.springframework.web.socket.adapter.AbstractWebSocketSession.checkNativeSessionInitialized() @bci=4, line=94 (Compiled frame)
 - org.springframework.web.socket.adapter.AbstractWebSocketSession.sendMessage(org.springframework.web.socket.WebSocketMessage) @bci=1, line=99 (Compiled frame)
 - com.example.SocketHandler.sendMessage(org.springframework.web.socket.WebSocketSession, java.lang.String, boolean) @bci=22, line=32 (Compiled frame)
 - com.example.RequestProcessor.handleRequest(org.springframework.web.socket.WebSocketSession, org.springframework.web.socket.TextMessage) @bci=620, line=123 (Compiled frame)
 - com.example.RequestProcessor.run() @bci=36, line=55 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call() @bci=4 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run() @bci=42 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker) @bci=95 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run() @bci=5 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.lang.Thread.run() @bci=11 (Interpreted frame)
```

I am using a jetty server in the Application with the default configuration. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You have idle threads in a thread pool in that list.

Those are waiting for tasks that need a thread, and are not blocked.

Example 1: - a waiting reserved thread pool thread.

```
 - java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(long, java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit) @bci=97 (Compiled frame)
 - org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.reservedWait() @bci=97, line=292 (Compiled frame)
```

Example 2: a QTP idle job poll.

```
 - org.eclipse.jetty.util.BlockingArrayQueue.poll(long, java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit) @bci=57, line=392 (Compiled frame)
 - org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.idleJobPoll() @bci=12, line=656 (Compiled frame)
```

Don't include those kinds of threads in your "all threads in a blocked state" concern.

Of the the 7 threads in your copy/paste ...

- 1 is active with networking behavior (don't know if it's client or server side)
- 1 is active with spring websocket behavior (looks like client side)
- 5 are idle in a thread pool and waiting for tasks to do something

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  The spring server was not able to connect to any client at that moment. It was not responding for heap dump as well. If the threads are not blocked then could you please tell me what could be the reason for the application hang?

Comment: It could be hundreds of different things, there's not enough information in your question to narrow it down.  The "not responding for heap dump" is pretty dramatic, and very unusual, even a badly written multithreaded app with tons of concurrency issues should not be able to prevent a heap dump.